# Missing Script: Start, Heroku Deployment Error

Tags: node.js, heroku

My Node.js script is unable to be deployed to Heroku and the error comes in the console saying that I'm missing my start script even though I have it.

Package.JSON

```
{
  "name": "kash",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" &amp;&amp; exit 1",
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

App.js

```
var express = require("express");
var request = require("request");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.listen((process.env.PORT || 5000));

// Server index page
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.send("Deployed!");
});

// Facebook Webhook
// Used for verification
app.get("/webhook", function (req, res) {
  if (req.query["hub.verify_token"] === process.env.VERIFICATION.TOKEN) {
    console.log("Verified webhook");
    res.status(200).send(req.query["hub.challenge"]);
  } else {
    console.error("Verification failed. The tokens do not match.");
    res.sendStatus(403);
  }
});
```

Console Log screenshots:

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwakh.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5q0Cn.png)

Comment: try using a procfile with the "node app"  in it.  see heroku docs on node

Comment: web: sh -c 'cd ./directory/ && node app'